# Clickable days from a List of days

Tags: android, user-interface

Hi all I have a question ,if someone can help me implement this design or give me a path to look from.
Actually i want to implement this UI , a user can select one ore more days ,when he selecte a day  the fond of the day  become **bold** when he unselect the day the style of the day become normal like Saturday in our case 
i tried to implement this UI using  toogle button but unfortunately i failed can anyone help me achieve this goal
[image]

thank you all for your help

Comment: on which step of this question do You have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this if you are using multiple TextView's in something like a LinearLayout.

```
public class BoldTextView extends TextView implements View.OnClickListener {

    private boolean bold  = false;

    public BoldTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (bold) {
            bold = false;
            setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else {
            bold = true;
            setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }

    public boolean isBold() {
        return bold;
    }
}
```